# Understanding the class SmtpDeliveryMethod

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

In my code, i am sending mail from an smtp server. I use the code snippet -

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

Besides Network, there are other ways too. What is the significance of these things ? The official docs don't make it clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question at - 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66257/Sending-Mails-in-NET-Framework

Luckily, my search words accidentally landed me on the right page.

Changing Mail Delivery Method
You can specify that messages sent do not go to the SMTP server. Instead, it is sent to a directory in your computer that you specify. Actually, it is a good idea when it comes to testing your application. Thus, decreases the testing time.

SmtpClient supports two properties for changing mail delivery location; they are DeliveryMethod and PickupDirectoryLocation properties. DeliveryMethod specifies the delivery method that would be taken when sending the message. This property is of type SmtpDeliveryMethod enumeration; therefore, it can be set to one of three values:

Network: (default)
The message is sent via the network to the SMTP server.

PickupDirectoryFromIis:
The message is copied to the mail default directory of the Internet Information Services (IIS).

SpecifiedPickupDirectory:
The message is copied to the directory specified by the property PickupDirectoryLocation.